# Extracting company, phone numbers and country while signing in with Google+ using python social auth

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I am working on implementing sign in with gplus in my website.  I have added the following settings :

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY = 'my-key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_SECRET = 'my-secret-key'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]
```

Sign in is successful.  I am able to get the following information about the authenticated user (`Username,email,firstname,lastname`).

How can I go about to get the company, country and phone numbers after signing in? Which scope should I use that will enable me to see this information?

Google plus asks for "`placesLived`" where the user enters which cities he has lived.  I am not sure how to get the country from this information.

I am using a custom pipeline for the create user `app.pipeline.user.create_user` which has `strategy,response and details` as arguments.  I don't see any of these fields `company,country,phone numbers` in the `details` or `response` received after sign in.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [People.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) at the very bottom  you will notice "try me".  you can test the results that the API will bring back for the different scopes.

The scopes you are using should be sufficient to give you the information you require.  The trick is that the user needs to have the information set to **public**.   If  I have not set my company name to public the API wont return the company name even if it is me that is Authenticated.

So my guess is you aren't getting this information back because your user hasn't set the information to public.  This has nothing to do with your python login, Try and test things using that Try it function at the bottom of the documentation page.

Comment: Hi @DalmTo. Thank you for your help, I am trying to implement this using **python social auth package**. After setting all the user information to public  and with the scopes i had defined, I can extract company and cities (Places Lived). I am not able to fetch phone numbers. Adding to this is there any way to get the country ??(not the places Lived)